# Service doesnt work correctly in Background

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am making Music Player which downloads music from Firebase.

Its working fine but I cannot play music in background.

It works for like 1.5 minute (after locking screen)  and it stops.

In logs after I lock screen it says "Inactivity, disconnecting from Service".

I think this may be main problem here.

[image]

Here code :

Fragment of Playing Music:

```
    public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {
        private FirebaseStorage storage;
    
        private ImageButton main_btn, next_btn, back_btn, fav_btn, settings_btn;
      private Uri localSong;
    private   Intent myService;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
          storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        main_btn=  view.findViewById(R.id.player_main_btn);
        next_btn=  view.findViewById(R.id.player_next_btn);
        back_btn=  view.findViewById(R.id.player_back_btn);
        fav_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.player_song_fav_btn);
        settings_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.player_song_options_btn);
    

            storage.getReference().child("songs/ni_bien_ni_mal.mp3").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    localSong=uri;
                }
            });
            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
             myService = new Intent(getActivity(), BackgroundSoundService.class);
    
    
    
            main_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    
                if( main_btn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals( main_btn.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play).getConstantState()))
                {
    
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            myService.putExtra("uri",localSong.toString() );
                            mainActivity.startService(myService);
                        }
                    }).start();
    
                   main_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                }
                else
                {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //  mainActivity.stopService(myService);
                            main_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                        }
                    }).start();
    
                }
    
    
            });
    
        fav_btn.setOnClickListener(v->{
    
            if( fav_btn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals( fav_btn.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_empty).getConstantState()))
            {
                fav_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_full);
            }else{
                fav_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_empty);
            }
        });
          return view;
        }
    }
```

Manifest: ( Service declaration is at bottom)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.company.altasnotas">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/altas_notes"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/altas_notes"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:testOnly="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AltasNotas">
    
    
    
            <activity
                android:name=".IntroActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AltasNotas.NoActionBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
                tools:replace="android:value" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="preloaded_fonts"
                android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    
            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            </activity>
            <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Service :

```
    public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
        String  song_string;
        int x;
        private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
        MediaPlayer player;
    
    
    
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
    
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
    
        }
    
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    
    
            song_string= intent.getStringExtra("uri");
    
            if (song_string != null) {
                    System.out.println("Song string : " + song_string);
                player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(song_string));
                player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
                player.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
                if (!(String.valueOf(x) == null || String.valueOf(x).isEmpty())) {
                    player.seekTo(x);
                }
                player.start();
            }
    
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
    
        public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
            return null;
        }
    
        public void onStop() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
        }
        public void onPause() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
            x=player.getCurrentPosition();
            player.pause();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if(player!=null) {
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
                player.release();
                 Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
        }
    
    
    }
```

Despite Sticky and declaration in Manifest , it still doesnt work in background. Also I want to add pause button and I dont know exacly how can I do that.

Comment: You need to start your service as a foreground Service

Comment: @Amin It doesnt work at all .Only 2s after locking screen also how to pause service?